# iPhone - How to add AdSupport.framework in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, frameworks, admob

I am trying to use the AdMob in my test application when I rum my application i am getting the following error as shown below.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADIdentifierUtilities.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
"_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
  -[GADOpener openInAppStore:fallbackURLString:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I googled around this errors and everyone telling to add the AdSupport.framework. But when I try to add that framework in my Xcode4.1 and Xcode4.4 there is no AdSupport.framework is not  missing. Where can I get it and how to add that framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AdSupport.framework available only in iOS6+, so you won't be able to find it in XCode version prior to 4.5

**UPD:**

According to AdMob 6.2.0 changelog:

- Required to use Xcode 4.5 and build against iOS 6. The minimum deployment is iOS 4.3.

Comment: Then how can i use AdMob in xcode4.1 and Xcode4.4 . I am targeting devices iOS 4.1 and above.

Comment: You can't use the latest AdMob library with iOS 4.1, because armv6 support was dropped in it, so use older version of AdMob if it still works. BTW, every day lots of libraries/frameworks drops armv6 (iOS prior to 4.3) support, so probably you will have to increase minimum required version of iOS to 4.3 soon.

Comment: Thank you very much. Where can i get the older version os AdMob. I can see only new version of sdk in AdMob.

Comment: Try this link: http://dl.google.com/googleadmobadssdk/googleadmobadssdkios_udid.zip Probably it's AdMob 6.1.5